# resolve service hostname in ECS fargate task

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, terraform, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am trying to automate my ECS fargate cluster making using terraform.

I have a SpringBoot project with microservices containerized, and I am putting these images in a single task definition for an ECS service for the backend.

The ECS cluster is initially running, but Kafka is getting stopped with the error :

```sh
ERROR Unable to resolve address: zookeeper:2181
(org.apache.zookeeper.client.StaticHostProvider)
```

I have given the image for *zookeeper(bitnami)* and used the KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT environment variable too.

EDIT : My task definition:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "this" {
  family                   = local.application_name
  requires_compatibilities = [local.launch_type]
  execution_role_arn       = data.aws_iam_role.ecs_task_execution_role.arn
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  cpu                      = "4096"
  memory                   = "30720"
  container_definitions = jsonencode([
    {
      name      = "zookeeper"
      image     = "docker.io/bitnami/zookeeper:latest"
      essential = true
      cpu       = 512
      memory    = 1024
      portMappings = [
        {
          containerPort = 2181
          hostPort      = 2181
        }
      ]
      "environment" : [
        { "name" : "ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN", "value" : "yes" },
        { "name" : "ZOO_LISTEN_ALLIPS_ENABLED", "value" : "yes" }
      ]
    },
    {
      name      = "kafka-server"
      image     = "docker.io/bitnami/kafka:latest"
      essential = true
      cpu       = 512
      memory    = 1024
      portMappings = [
        {
          containerPort = 9092
          hostPort      = 9092
        }
      ]
      depends_on =  [
        "zookeeper"
      ]
      "environment" : [
        { "name" : "KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT", "value" : "zookeeper:2181" },
        { "name" : "ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN", "value" : "yes" },
        { "name" : "ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER", "value" : "yes" }
      ],
    },
    {
      name      = "email-service"
      image     = "my-email-image"
      essential = true
      cpu       = 512
      memory    = 1024
      portMappings = [
        {
          containerPort = 8090
          hostPort      = 8090
        }
      ]
      "environment" : [
        { "name" : "EMAIL_URL", "value" : "email-service" },
        { "name" : "EMAIL_PORT", "value" : "8090" },
        { "name" : "KAFKA_URL", "value" : "kafka-server" },
        { "name" : "KAFKA_PORT", "value" : "9092" },
      ]
    }
  ])
}
```

Comment: If you give a name like this, it's using DNS. I think you should change `zookeeper` to the `FQDN` of your zookeeper deployment. I doubt it's simply zookeeper. Can you share your task definition?

Comment: @TheFool I have included task definition in question edit and I think I might have used `depends_on` incorrectly but was not getting any error in `terraform plan` .

Comment: Your issue might be that you have network mode set to `awsvpc`. I am not sure if you can simply use the service name like that anymore, if you do that.  Can you try to set it to `bridge` once and see if it works? Then you know at least where to look for further configuration if it's that. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#network_mode

Comment: @TheFool I am using Fargate and it does not support `bridge`, btw thanks for the doc link I got the correct way to use dependsOn but it's still giving the same error!

Comment: Why don't you just create an MSK cluster with terraform? Specifically, Zookeeper nor Kafka are persistent here, so you're going to lose all data when the containers restart

Comment: I think this sentence is the key:  *"Additionally, containers that belong to the same task can communicate over the localhost interface."* Can you try to set `KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT` to `localhost:2181` ? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/fargate-task-networking.html

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for informing but sadly that's one of the requirements and cannot be changed

Comment: What exactly are the requirements? Like I said, the data isn't persistent, so you might as well just use Spring's internal EventListener classes or some other embedded event bus library

Comment: From the same docs page this one seems also relevant: *"Amazon ECS populates the hostname of the task with an Amazon-provided (internal) DNS hostname when both the `enableDnsHostnames` and `enableDnsSupport` options are enabled on your VPC. If these options are not enabled, the DNS hostname of the task will be a random hostname. "*

Comment: As mentioned above, multiple containers in a single task deployed to Fargate will have to communicate with each other via `localhost`. They don't resolve each other's DNS names, like "zookeeper", like they would in something like a docker-compose environment.

Comment: Thank you @TheFool, the issue was solved using localhost.

Comment: @TheFool could you post that in the answer so I could mark it

Comment: Ok, I did that. Thanks for the sportsmanship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AS written in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/fargate-task-networking.html):

> Additionally, containers that belong to the same task can communicate over the localhost interface.

So my suggestion is to use localhost instead of the service names. For example, you want to do it for Kafka but also for *every* other service, such as the email service.

```json
{ "name" : "KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT", "value" : "localhost:2181" },
```